# LINQ Query not returning results

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ query that I can't figure out why it does not return any results ever, even when the conditions are true.

I pass in `TBL_CONTACTAddress contactAddress, pPeople person` to my method.

My LINQ query looks like:

```
pPeople_Address recordExists = people
    .Select(p => p.pPeople_Address
                  .Where(a => a.People_ID == person.ID 
                          &&  a.Address1  == contactAddress.LINE1)
                  .FirstOrDefault())
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

If I hover over the last `FirstOrDefault()` it says it is returning `pPeople_Address`.  When I debug on it, both `person.ID` and `contactAddress.LINE1` are providing the correct inputs.  The record exists in `IEnumerable<pPeople> people`.

I am missing something here?

EDIT1:  The first part Gets the entities.

```
        using (CRMEntities crm = new CRMEntities())
        {
            people = crm.pPeoples.Where(p => p.import_num == ImportNumber).Select(p => p).AsEnumerable().ToList();
        }
```

The second part is updating information and seeing if the record exists

```
private void GetAddressGeneric(TBL_CONTACT contact, pPeople person, CRMEntities crm)
    {
            foreach (TBL_ADDRESS contactAddress in contact.TBL_ADDRESS.Where(n => n.LINE1 != null))
            {
                var address = new pPeople_Address();

                pPeople_Address recordExists = people.Select(p => p.pPeople_Address.FirstOrDefault(a => a.People_ID == person.ID && a.Address1 == contactAddress.LINE1)).FirstOrDefault();

    }
```

EDIT2:  The below code accomplishes what I want, but I want to be able to do it in one single LINQ statement

```
                var recordExists = people.FirstOrDefault(p => p.pPeople_Address.Any(a => 
                                                                                    a.People_ID == person.ID && 
                                                                                    a.Address1 == contactAddress.LINE1));
                pPeople_Address record = recordExists.pPeople_Address.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Provide a complete compilable example that demonstrates your problem, in this case create an example data structure with enough data that it should return a result but that doesn't.

Comment: Are you sure that the "people" variable contains the information you are filtering for does exist based on the filtering field person.ID and contactAddress.LINE1 ?

Comment: What you want to select? pPeople_Address or people object?

Comment: The FirstOrDefault following the Where clause can be combined as the FirstOrDefault accepts a predicate lambda.

Comment: I am trying to return the first result of pPeople_Address that matches the condition.  Ill update my code to provide a more thorough code example

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying, in a single Linq request, to get the first address entry (of any people) that matches the specified `person.ID` and `contactAddress.LINE1` values then you should try this code :

```
pPeople_Address recordExists = people.SelectMany(p => p.pPeople_Address)
                                     .FirstOrDefault(a => a.People_ID == person.ID &&
                                                          a.Address1 == contactAddress.LINE1);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would rewrite your expression to something like:

```
    pPeople_Address recordExists = 
        people.Where(a => a.People_ID == person.ID && a.Address1 == contactAddress.LINE1)
        .Select(p => p.pPeople_Address)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

If you're still not getting your desired results, you may try debugging some intermediate variables to find out where the problem lies. For example:

```
    var matchingPeople = 
        people.Where(a=> a.People_ID == person.ID && a.Address1 == contactAddress.LINE1).ToList(); // Depending on your data, calling ToList() on this expression may not be feasible
    var matchingAddresses = 
        matchingPeople.Select(p => p.pPeople_Address).ToList();
    var firstMatchingAddress = 
        matchingAddresses.FirstOrDefault();
```

Note: LINQ query operations are deferred which means that until you try to actually consume the data, the query is not executed. This is why calls like ToList() and FirstOrDefault() are necessary to get concrete results.

Edit: Based on your "EDIT 2", I believe what you are looking for is

```
    pPeople_Address record = (from p in people
                             from a in p.people_Address
                             where a.People_ID == person.ID && a.Address1 == contact.Address.LINE1
                             select a).FirstOrDefault();
```

Sorry for the query syntax, but in my opinion, this is the cleanest way to do what I think you're trying for.